# JPA Entiy on synonym instead of table

Tags: hibernate, jpa, oracle10g, seam, java-ee-5

I have a Seam 2.2 based Java EE 5 web application with a bunch of tables mapped to JPA 1.0 Entities via Hibernate 3.3.3. During development it's running on a Tomcat 6, Oracle 10 XE and Windows 7.

Now, we had the request by operations department to split the data model into one schema being the owner of all database objects (`myschema`) and one schema acting as the application's database user (`myschema_app`). So I did the following:

- create schema `myschema_app`
- grant object rights on all necessary tables from `myschema` (both regular ones and n:m intermediate tables) and sequences depending on the usage (one or more of `select`, `insert`, `update`, `delete`) to `myschema_app`
- declare private synonyms in `myschema_app` in order to use the same names than before and hiding the other schema's name prefix
- change property `hibernate.default_schema` to new schema name in `persistence.xml`
- change user/password in Tomcat's datasource definition in `context.xml`

When I start the application while having `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto`set to `validate`, I get an exception when the framework tries to create the `EntityManagerFactory` telling me that a table is missing. When I execute a select statement directly in an sql tool with `myschema_app` connected, everything works fine.

I understood that using a synonym going on another table is transparent for the application. Has anyone an idea what I may have overlooked?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My guess is that hbm2ddl seaches specifically for tables, and not for synonyms, but that your application should indeed work as if the tables existed in the schema. Try to remove the hbm2ddl option and test your application.

EDIT: it seems my guess is true: https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2438033

Comment: That was some quick reply, 10 points earned. Yep, I have already seen, that omiting that parameter makes the application work, but it's a pity that Hibernate doesn't support synonyms during validation, because I think it's a good thing to validate the schema at startup to make sure it fits the application.

Comment: The problem is in hibernates org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata class where the table types are hardcoded to 

private static final String[] TYPES = {"TABLE", "VIEW"}; where it really should be 

private static final String[] TYPES = {"TABLE", "VIEW", "ALIAS", "SYNONYM"};

Answer (score 5):

As of 4.3.0, It is possible to set `hibernate.synonyms=true` to solve your problem with synonyms.

References:

https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/commit/1df4b2ea3c98c74f3b6bbd42e266ee5c7ad60d27

https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8183

https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/pull/508

Answer (score 0):

I still had validation issues because my Oracle driver was not giving the right columns even after setting `hibernate.synonyms=true`, so instead of disabling schema validation entirely I filtered the synonym table out:

In properties:

```
hbm2ddl.schema_filter_provider=my.path.to.MyCustomSchemaFilterProvider
```

Define schema filter provider:

```
package my.path.to;
..
public class MyCustomSchemaFilterProvider implements SchemaFilterProvider {
    @Override
    public SchemaFilter getCreateFilter() {
        return MySchemaFilter.INSTANCE;
    }

    @Override
    public SchemaFilter getDropFilter() {
        return MySchemaFilter.INSTANCE;
    }

    @Override
    public SchemaFilter getMigrateFilter() {
        return MySchemaFilter.INSTANCE;
    }

    @Override
    public SchemaFilter getValidateFilter() {
        return MySchemaFilter.INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

SchemaFilter:

```
..
public class MySchemaFilter implements SchemaFilter {
    public static final MySchemaFilter INSTANCE = new MySchemaFilter();

    @Override
    public boolean includeNamespace(Namespace namespace) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean includeTable(Table table) {
        if (table.getName().toLowerCase().equals("synonymtabletoexclude")){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean includeSequence(Sequence sequence) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

This was based off of https://medium.com/@horiaconstantin/excluding-hibernate-entities-from-auto-generation-bce86f8e6d94